Как в flash-сообщении javaScript передать html-код
Хочу сделать сообщение об ошибке "Данного пользователя не существует! Зарегистрируйтесь". Слово "Зарегистрируйтесь" должно быть ссылкой на соответствующую страницу. Как из flash-сообщения считать html-код? Я использую шаблонизатор ejs.
Мое сообщение:
req.flash('error', `Пользователя с таким email не существует! <a href="./registration.ejs">Зарегистрируйтесь.</a>`);
ejs-код:
<% if (error) { %>
  <div id="error"><%= error %></div>
<% } %>


А зачем что-то писать на JS, если это можно сразу сформировать на той же стороне, что и сама ошибка?

Так у меня ошибку сервер генерирует. Мне же надо ее как-то в клиенте вставить

Если вы уже вставляете див, так вставляйте его вместе ссылкой. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

Беда в том, что часть сообщения - обычный текст. Его не нужно ссылкой делать Я скинул пример сообщения, как я хочу сделать. Только часть ошибки должна быть обведена в html-тег

Сделал, просто добавив такую конструкцию
        <% if (error) { %>
            <div class="error-wrapper">
                <div id="error"><%= error %></div>
                <a class="error_link" href="/auth"><b><%= error_link %></b></a>
            </div>
            
        <% } %>

А с сервера передавал просто 2 сообщения сразу
